How to to set the value using Iterator in array of map
Im beginner in JAVA and trying to learn data structure and object conversion. I have below data structure in yaml file.
    ingress: {backendServiceName: serv-abc-lc002, cluster_issuer: letsencrypt-oe-dev-001,
      ingressClassName: nginx-lc002, tls_acme: 'true'}
    route:
      hosts:
        abcygyPM:
          active: false
          host: cir11.abc.com
          logicalclustername: lc002
          offboardtimestamp: null
          physicalclustername: oe-dev-001
          region: us-east-1
          status: Triggered
          timestamp: |-
            {
              "timestamp": "2024-02-05T14:43:18.00847359Z"
            }
        hXDmziFYnT:
          active: false
          host: sign.abc.com
          logicalclustername: lc002
          offboardtimestamp: null
          physicalclustername: oe-dev-001
          region: us-east-1
          status: Triggered
          timestamp: |-
            {
              "timestamp": "2024-02-08T05:45:35.615793284Z"
            }

Using snakeyaml library, Im able to load yaml content in POJO
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Automation\\values.yaml"));

        Yaml yamlrm = new Yaml(new Constructor(Values1.class));

        Values1 datarm = yamlrm.load(inputStream);
        String url = "cir11.abc.com";

        Iterator<Entry<String, Host>> iterator = datarm.getRoute().getHosts().entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (iterator.next().getValue().getHost().equals(url)) {
           
             << need to write the code here >> ??
    
            }

        }

    }

Host.java
   public class Host {
 
     private String host;
     private String physicalclustername;
     private String logicalclustername;
     private String status;
     @Expose
     private String onboardtimestamp;
     private String offboardtimestamp;
     private boolean active;

     <<getter and setter >>
   }

Values1.java
    public class Values1 {
    
      private Route route;
      private Ingress ingress;
    
      <<getter setter >>
    }

Route.java
    public class Route {
    
      private Map<String, Host> hosts;
    
      <<geter setter>>
    }

what Im trying to do is , set the value of field active to true if the url matches to "cir11.abc.com"
I learn about iterator but not able to understand , how can i use Iterator to set the values in array of hashmap
if not through iterator, what is the way to set the values , please suggest
update 1
it is not going in if loop
 for (Map.Entry<String, Host> entry : datarm.getRoute().getHosts().entrySet()) {
                 if (entry.getValue().getHost().equals(url)) {
                     System.out.println("in loop");
                   entry.getValue().setActive(true);
                 }
               }


When running through the entries you can just set the active property:
   Iterator<Entry<String, Host>> iterator = datarm.getRoute().getHosts().entrySet().iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       Host host = iterator.next().getValue().getHost();
       if (host.equals(url)) {
            host.setActive(true);
       }
   }

You could optimize your code further by using a for-loop on the map entries instead of the while:
   for (Map.Entry<String, Host> entry : datarm.getRoute().getHosts()) {
     if (entry.getValue().getHost().equals(url)) {
       entry.getValue().setActive(true);
     }
   }


sorry to say , but not working . I used the optimised solution , but not working . PLease see update 1

it worked . entrySet was missing
